# Hide/Show rows using tick button in ngGrid table (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, ng-show, angular-ng-if, ng-hide

it may be asked by someone before, but I checked Q&As and could not find the relevant answer for my question. So I am using an ng-grid table, which displays more than 30K data on that table. The data that I display is coming from the server, it is a real-time data. I have multiple columns in my table. Sometimes the value of 3,4 cells in one row are zero. So I want to have a tick/untick button, which which will hide/show those zero cells based on my choice. How can I do it? Using ng-hide? if yes, how should call it? I would appreciate, if you gave me ideas. I can provide you my code, if you need so. Thanks in advance!

**js**

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, Stream, liveData) {

$scope.myData = liveData.myData;
$scope.$apply();
};

    Stream.start();

    var customCell = '<div ng-class="{red: row.getProperty(col.field) < 0, blue: row.getProperty(col.field) > 0 , black: row.getProperty(col.field) == 0}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field) | number | replace}}</div></div>';
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        showFilter: true,
        showColumnMenu: true,
        showFooter: true,

    columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'name',
                displayName: 'Name',
                cellClass: 'text-center',

            },

            {
                field: 'amountSent',
                displayName: 'Amount Sent',
                cellClass: 'text-center'
            },  

            {
                field: 'amountReceived',
                displayName: 'Amount Received',
                cellClass: 'text-center'
            },
                field: 'currentBalance',
                displayName: 'Current balance',
                cellTemplate: customCell,
                cellClass: 'text-right'
     ],

    };

});
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="Table">
<head>
    <title>Payments</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="/Scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/ng-grid.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/indexStyle.css" />

</head>

<body>        
    <div ng-view></div>
    <h1>Payment Table</h1>
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jscript/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/Jscript/MyController.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ng-grid.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple method like "toogle()";

You should check [**this**](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_events)

And you can find more **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp)**
Maybe you can define this method in your controller. As you wish my friend. Good luck... If you need more help contact me again ;)